# Scroll parent to top of child element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to scroll a div so that a link inside of it appears on top.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    scrollit();
  
  
});

function scrollit(){
  
   var elem= $("#link10");
         
 if(elem.length){
  console.log(elem.offset().top);
  $("#sidebar").animate({ scrollTop: elem.offset().top }, { duration: 'medium', easing: 'swing' });
 }
  
  
}
```

```css
#sidebar{
  
  height:80px;
  width:200px;
  overflow:scroll;
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='sidebar'>
         <a href='#' id='link1'>1</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link2'>2</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link3'>3</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link4'>4</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link5'>5</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link6'>6</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link7'>7</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link8'>8</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link9'>9</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link10'>10</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link11'>11</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link12'>12</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link13'>13</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link14'>14</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link15'>15</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link16'>16</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link17'>17</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link18'>18</a>
    </div>

<br/><br/>
<a href='#' onclick='scrollit();return false'>again</a>
```

At first, it will log the offset as being a certain distance (say 45), and will scroll to there correctly. Then, if it runs again, the logged distance is 0 and will then scroll to the top of the sidebar. It should say at that element.

Comment: your question is not clear .. how can you scroll parent to top of child element ...  Is it that you want to scroll the child link to the top or starting of parent div ??

Comment: yes, see code snippet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code works fine as you can see in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yatiqa/2/edit)

The problem is that the `elem.offset().top` value is relative to the current scroll position so you have to take that in account and either reset the scroll or discount the scroll position (with something like `window.pageYOffset`).

**UPDATE:**

Solution by danielb:

```
$("#sidebar").animate({ scrollTop: $("#sidebar").scrollTop()+elem.offset().top }, { duration: 'medium', easing: 'swing' });
```

Comment: please pay attention to the answer

Comment: do you have an example? The pageoffset doesn't work since the offset is of the div element

Comment: This answer is closest. The solution:
$("#sidebar").animate({ scrollTop: $("#sidebar").scrollTop()+elem.offset().top }, { duration: 'medium', easing: 'swing' });

Comment: my bad daniel ... pageYOffset would help you if the body were being scrolled ... i'm happy that you managed to find a solution

Comment: This doesn't work for my case. If you have the parent div positioned inside an absolute parent, then for me 
$("#sidebar").animate({ scrollTop: $("#sidebar").scrollTop()+elem.position().top }, { duration: 'medium', easing: 'swing' });
would work. Using offset only made it jumped up and down

Comment: Curious - is this achievable using the angular 7 animation module?  I haven't had success with it, so I'm asking if anyone else has.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the animation from triggering again once the item is on top using an additional condition as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(scrollit);

function scrollit(){
  
  var elem = $("#link10");
  if(elem.length && elem.position().top){
     $("#sidebar").animate({ scrollTop: elem.position().top }, { duration: 'medium', easing: 'swing' });
  }
}
```

```css
#sidebar{
  
  height:80px;
  width:200px;
  overflow:scroll; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='sidebar'>
         <a href='#' id='link1'>1</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link2'>2</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link3'>3</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link4'>4</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link5'>5</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link6'>6</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link7'>7</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link8'>8</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link9'>9</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link10'>10</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link11'>11</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link12'>12</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link13'>13</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link14'>14</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link15'>15</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link16'>16</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link17'>17</a><br/>
         <a href='#' id='link18'>18</a>
    </div>

<br/><br/>
<a href='#' onclick='scrollit();return false'>again</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is find parents top offset and subtract it with link's top offset that will always give you the distance between the two ..

```
var childPos = obj.offset();
var parentPos = obj.parent().offset();
var childOffset = {
    top: childPos.top - parentPos.top,
    left: childPos.left - parentPos.left
}
```

but make sure that the parent div has position relative or absolute (css)..

Comment: this isn't working. parentPos is always 0 (div is fixed to top)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The solution:

```
  $("#sidebar").animate({ scrollTop: $("#sidebar").scrollTop()+elem.offset().top }, { duration:'medium', easing: 'swing' });
```